# Gallery crashes on invoking from app: Android 3.0 SDK

Tags: android

I am invoking the gallery, so that a user can select a photo to import into my app, however, the gallery just seems to crash as soon as it is invoked...

Any ideas if this is a known issue or would I be doing something wrong by invoking using the following:

```
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

Or the following:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

Thanks,
Sonny

Answer (score 1):

Tested on an actual Xoom, seems to work fine:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),
                        SOME_REQUEST_CODE);
```

(I suppose it's the "INTERNAL" vs. "EXTERNAL" content URI).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Yoni, but I should have said - I have tried that variation too... I think it's an emulator problem. Will see if anyone else has any tips.

Comment: Very likely an emulator problem, especially as the Xoom has already gotten a software update to 3.0.1 which the emulator hasn't. Do you have a stack trace handy? (Also, make sure your emulator image was set up with an SD card).

Comment: I've re-run the app with the 2.2 emulator and it works, so I raised a defect (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15870)

SD Card is setup and going into the Gallery via the UI shows the Image I pushed to it, but thanks for the tips ;)